# powershell command - wait until visual studio solution loading

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that launches Visual Studio with a solution and run a macro.

devenv.exe "$PATH\TestSolution.sln" /Command Macros.MyMacros.TestMacro

However, it takes time to load the solution so that the macro doesn't run.

Is there a way to wait(sleep) for 15 second and run the macro?

Answer (score 0):

Suspends the activity in a script or session for the specified period of time. use Start-sleep http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849939.aspx